# How to receive IdP token manually?

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, claims-based-identity, acs

I'm trying to build this scenario in windows client:

[Picture of my desired scenario](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-wikis-components-files/00-00-00-00-05/8156.SWT-REST-LiveID-Facebook-Google-OpenID-Solution.png)

Steps I did:

1. Client starts; it opens a window with a choice of the identity providers
2. End-user choose one of the identity providers (let's say Google)
3. It goes to next tab, where web-browser navigates to Google sign-in screen.
4. User signs-in, and authentication token (user id, etc.) are received.
5. Now I can login using Mobile Services, and access Azure tables, all is fine.

But now we want to use WCF service. How to obtain the IdP token in this scenario, to be used to obtain ACS SWT Token. I have access token, authentication token, user id, and much more information from IdP, but how can I either catch or forge IdP token from these informations?

I want to be able to access Azure table in a WCF service, while having the identity of a signed user from the client-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after intensive search, I've found these links useful:

- [Azure ACS on Windows Phone 7](http://blog.tylerdoerksen.com/2011/04/12/azure-acs-on-windows-phone-7/)
- [How To: Obtain SWT Security Token](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2011/09/09/displaying-list-of-identity-providers-idp-s-for-specific-acs-namespace-in-wpf-application.aspx)
- [How To: Display List Of Identity Providers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2011/09/09/displaying-list-of-identity-providers-idp-s-for-specific-acs-namespace-in-wpf-application.aspx)
- [How to: Authenticate to a REST WCF Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2011/06/05/how-to-request-swt-token-from-acs-and-how-to-validate-it-at-the-rest-wcf-service-hosted-in-windows-azure.aspx)